# How to customize a WebSphere Portal 8.0 CSA theme?

Tags: themes, websphere-portal

I'm using WebSphere Portal 8.0 and want to create a new theme, a CSA (Client Side Aggregation) based theme, but when I follow IBM's instructions to use WebDAV to create a new custom theme, the only theme available under the /wps/mycontenthandler/dav/themelist location is ibm.portal.80theme, and that theme is not a CSA theme. In my search I found the site: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/dev/csa2r_prguide_csm.dita?lang=en which cnofirms that the default Portal 8.0 theme does not support CSA.

Am I missing something?  From what I've learned so far, PageBuilder and PageBuilder2 themes support CSA, and could be what I want.  When I've looked at similar instructions for WebSphere Portal 7.0 (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_new_PageBuilder2_custom_theme_wp7) it states that the PageBuilder2 that is shipped with the portal can be chosen from the same WebDAV location.  What happened to that option in Portal 8.0??  How can I create a new CSA based theme from WebSphere Portal 8.0?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would only have those older referenced themes if you upgraded a WPS7 instance in-place or if perhaps you cloned a PageBuilder theme on WP7 and migrated it to WPS8 (in which case your own custom theme would be in the list).

I think by virtue of the fact that these style themes are unavailable and discouraged, you should read into it that it's a bad idea to try to extend the JSR-286 programming model out to the client side. It seems to me to be what CSA functionality tried to do (and did, to some extent).  However, this turns out to be tremendously complex and hard to maintain.

I'd recommend instead using portlets or widgets that render RESTful resource responses client-side and collaborate together using loose-coupling mechanisms such as [dojo/topic](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/topic.html) or jQuery callbacks.

Then your custom theme can just be a theme and not a portlet intercommunication engine.

Comment: I appreciate the insight.  I had started to question whether IBM was trying to discourage the older practices or if I simply wasn't able to find the solutions that I thought were out there.  Assuming that IBM is trying to make the CSA themes obsolete, along with the client-side capabilities, then I need to learn what the new alternatives are that you referred to.  I've opened a ticket with IBM and will hopefully have a definitive answer and clearer direction to follow soon.  I'll report back here when I have an answer.